# How to showing line one by one in async code?

Tags: swift, macos, for-loop, asynchronous, appkit

I want to do for-loop code with async. For simulating the async, I added some delays.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    private let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue.global()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 1...10 {
            if run(i) {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func run(_ i:Int) -> Bool{
        let seed = arc4random()
        let isSuccess = seed % 5 == 1
        let delayInSeconds = Int(seed % 3)

        concurrentQueue.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + .seconds(delayInSeconds)) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textView.string += "\(i)\t\(seed)\n"
            }

            self.semaphore.signal()
        }

        semaphore.wait()

        return isSuccess
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!
}
```

The problem is, when the code runs, all lines were added at once. I want it added one by one. Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved. The reason that update UI part doesn't work is because that `func run()` is running on main thread, which is blocked by `semaphore.wait()` always. So to solve the problem, just added it to another thread.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    concurrentQueue.async {
        for i in 1...10 {
            if self.run(i) {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```